# Moodle SQL query to retrieve all users enrolled to a course in the past 90 days

Tags: mysql, moodle

I need an SQL query that will give me all users enrolled to a course in the last 90 days that are not suspended.

I have done some searching and found this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id AS userid, c.id AS courseid
FROM mdl_user u
JOIN mdl_user_enrolments ue ON ue.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_enrol e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
JOIN mdl_role_assignments ra ON ra.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_context ct ON ct.id = ra.contextid AND ct.contextlevel = 50
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = ct.instanceid AND e.courseid = c.id
JOIN mdl_role r ON r.id = ra.roleid AND r.shortname = 'student'
WHERE e.status = 0 AND u.suspended = 0 AND u.deleted = 0
  AND (ue.timeend = 0 OR ue.timeend > NOW()) AND ue.status = 0
```

I can return results from a specific course by adding `AND courseid = 11` to the end of the query, but i'm still struggling with the date range.

I've tried using:

```
AND ue.timecreated BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND NOW()
```

but that is returning no results i even tried to add 2000 day range and it returns nothing

this is my current modified query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id AS userid, c.id AS courseid, DATE_FORMAT(ue.timecreated, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM mdl_user u
JOIN mdl_user_enrolments ue ON ue.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_enrol e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
JOIN mdl_role_assignments ra ON ra.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_context ct ON ct.id = ra.contextid
AND ct.contextlevel =50
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = ct.instanceid
AND e.courseid = c.id
JOIN mdl_role r ON r.id = ra.roleid
AND r.shortname =  'student'
WHERE e.status =0
AND u.suspended =0
AND u.deleted =0
AND (
ue.timeend =0
OR ue.timeend > NOW()
)
AND ue.status =0
AND ue.timecreated BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1200 DAY AND NOW()
AND courseid = 11
```

And that return nothing, as soon as I remove the second-last line that contains the date range I receive all the results inside course id 11.

Basically I need:

A list of all users that are enrolled in to a specific course in the last 90 days that is not suspended or deleted.

Results would be something like:

```
course id: 20
user id: 200, 533, 221, 22, 356
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Configurable Reports plugin at all? It may not suit your needs specifically, but it is incredibly powerful and you can put raw SQL in to generate formatted, sortable reports within Moodle.

See https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Configurable_reports#Creating_a_users.27_report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the solution is here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id AS userid, c.id AS courseid, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(ue.timecreated),'%m/%d/%Y') AS timecreated
FROM mdl_user u
JOIN mdl_user_enrolments ue ON ue.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_enrol e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
JOIN mdl_role_assignments ra ON ra.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_context ct ON ct.id = ra.contextid
AND ct.contextlevel =50
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = ct.instanceid
AND e.courseid = c.id
JOIN mdl_role r ON r.id = ra.roleid
AND r.shortname =  'student'
WHERE e.status =0
AND u.suspended =0
AND u.deleted =0
AND (
ue.timeend =0
OR ue.timeend > NOW( )
)
AND ue.status =0
AND courseid =11
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(ue.timecreated) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 4):

The times in Moodle are stored as integers and are a UTC unix timestamp. So the date functions in MySql won't work - unless they are converted using FROM_UNIXTIME().

If you want all users enrolled, not just students, then this is simpler.

```
SELECT ue.id, e.courseid, ue.userid, e.enrol AS enrolmethod, FROM_UNIXTIME(ue.timecreated)
FROM mdl_user_enrolments ue
JOIN mdl_enrol e ON e.id = ue.enrolid AND e.status = 0
JOIN mdl_user u ON u.id = ue.userid AND u.deleted = 0 AND u.suspended = 0
WHERE ue.timecreated >= 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 AND ue.status = 0
```

A user could be enrolled using more than one method though. So if you just want the userid and courseid then use a group by rather than a distinct.

```
SELECT CONCAT(e.courseid, '_', ue.userid) AS uniqueid, e.courseid, ue.userid, FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(ue.timecreated))
FROM mdl_user_enrolments ue
JOIN mdl_enrol e ON e.id = ue.enrolid AND e.status = 0
JOIN mdl_user u ON u.id = ue.userid AND u.deleted = 0 AND u.suspended = 0
WHERE ue.status = 0
GROUP BY e.courseid, ue.userid
HAVING MAX(ue.timecreated) >= 90 * 24 * 60 * 60
```